# Can items affect my chances of finding an angel room?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

In Binding of Isaac, I would like to know if there are any specific items that lower chances of finding an angel room.

I know that taking deals with the devil does, but how about specific items?

Answer (score 3):

In the Binding of Isaac there are no items dedicated to **lowering** your angel room chance. Like you said the only way to lower the chance of finding an angel room is by taking a deal with the devil.

There are a few items and actions that you can use to **increase** your angel room chance but there are no ways to lower the chance, possibly due to the ease of completely removing your chance of finding one by taking a deal with the devil.

Source: [Binding of Isaac Wiki](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Angel_Room)

Comment: There are quite a lot of things that lower your chance of finding an angel room: Black markets, donating to a devil beggar, blowing up donation machines and blowing up normal beggars.

Comment: This is also Binding of Isaac not Rebirth. Black Markets do not exist, neither do donation machines. Also the question said items not events and there are no items that lower chances. @Jutschge

Comment: Oops yeah I misread the tag.

Comment: @Jutschge no worries, if the OP is meaning Rebirth I will edit this to reflect that but with only BoI the options are kind of limited to affect rate.

Comment: Mentioning events would certainly be a good addition to the answer though. (I also missed that it was about the original and not rebirth)

Comment: I'll do an edit to this in a bit to talk about events in BOI that affect your angel room chances. Sadly though after Rebirth was released it is a LOT harder to find BoI information for the original game.

Answer (score -1):

Or you can get hit with your red health to completely eliminate your chases with any "Angelic or Devil" room for the entirety of the floor